# angular2 css style doesn't work for dynamicly created element?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Issue: In angular2, note.component.css file doesn't work for dynamically created element within note.component.ts. Does anyone know the reason? Or is it the correct behaviour?

note.component.css can work for element already existed in note.component.html. 
If I put the css style in file "styles.css", it worked. If I set the style with DOM, it worked.

File structure:

```
app
    components
        note
            note.component.css
            note.component.html
            note.component.ts
index.html
styles.css
```

note.component.html:

```
<div id="section1"></div>
```

note.component.css:

```
button{
    background-color: green; //doesn't work
}
```

styles.css:

```
button{
    background-color: green; //worked
}
```

note.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    var div = document.createElement("button"); 
    div.innerHTML = "Hello world";
    // div.style.backgroundColor = "green"; --- worked
    document.getElementById("section1").appendChild(div);
  }
```

Comment: The poor man's solution is to remove View Encapsulation. The proper way is to use *ngIf to create and destroy the desired div instead of using DOM manipulation in your component.

Comment: Actually, I’m creating a folder manage tool, like [this](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC151268.jpg). User can create/delete/expand/collapse any folder. That’s why I choose DOM and give up ngIf or ngFor. I want elements to be dynamically created under clicked folder. Do you have any better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#controlling-view-encapsulation-native-emulated-and-none) of the Component. By default it is set to `Emulated` which will wrap all of the Component's view into a separate 'scope'. There are two ways of fixing it:

1) Set the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None`

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

2) Prefix your css with `:host /deep/`

```css
:host /deep/ button {
    background-color: green;
}
```

*EDIT and yes like William B said you shouldn't manipulate the DOM like this. Take a look at [#2 here](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)

Comment: it's worth noting that the semantic solution is not to continue creating Elements in your `ngOnInit` and just remove view encapsulation - these are anti patterns. Instead he should have the desired div in the template and simply create/destroy it with *ngIf

Comment: Right, I should have specified the correct way to do it as well, but also wanted to give him a solution to what he was currently working with.

Comment: Great thanks for your answers. I will try the two solutions.

Comment: Actually, I’m creating a folder manage tool, like [link](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC151268.jpg). User can create/delete/expand/collapse any folder. That’s why I choose DOM and give up ngIf or ngFor. I want elements to be dynamically created under certain folder. Do you have any better idea?